# I cannot install requests module on my computer

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, request, discord.py

I get this error when I run my python project(I'm using python 3.10.5 on Windows 10):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Despite the fact that I do infact have the [module installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ckj8.png). I also tried uninstalling it and installing it again, but that didn't work. I had a conflict on my other computer again with requests and installing discord.py, but I can't seem to get it to work here. I installed discord.py v2 using:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Command Prompt Type: py -3 -m pip install requests
If it doesn't install, go to the given address and delete all the folders that say requests and upload again.

Comment: It worked, but now my discord module stopped working. Any ideas?

Comment: Install the Discord module with py -3 -m. But first, delete the files of the discord module.

Comment: py -3 -m install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py ?

Comment: Install it from Github and move it to AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages.

Comment: Still not working, unfortunately. I downloaded the repo as a zip and extracted it there and I still get: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'" and if I just install discord.py I get the error that the discord repo stuff isn't working. For example: "AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'ui'"

Comment: Move the py file to the previous folder Lib, not the site-packages location. Delete ZIP File after adding py File to Lib folder

Comment: Thanks a lot! It didn't work at first, but I renamed the file from discord.py - master to discord.py, that didn't fix anything I don't think but then I uninstalled discord.py using "pip uninstall discord.py", put the file back in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib and then installed discord.py with the command: "pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py "